# Effective way to remove white spaces from string

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel

I have come up with this approach but I'm not convinced about its effectiveness. Is there any effective approach?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Container,  typename UnaryPredicate>
auto remove_if(Container& c, UnaryPredicate pred)
    -> decltype(c.begin())
{
    auto it = std::begin(c);
    while (it != std::end(c))
    {
        if(pred(*it))
        {
            it = c.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    return it;
}

template <typename Container, typename T>
auto remove(Container& c,  T const& value)
    -> decltype(c.begin())
{
    return remove_if(c,  [&](T const& t) { return t == value; });
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = " Text with some spaces ";
    remove(str, ' ');
    std::cout << str ;
}
```

Comment: Stop trying to re-invent things that are already in the standard. Thats just silly. The standard implementation will be the most efficient way to do something (it has been reviewed by actually experts to make sure it is efficient).

Comment: If you are aware of the existence of standard functions for this purpose, it might be adequate tagging this as [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### General Comment

Stop trying to re-invent the wheel.
Or at least go look at a more interesting wheel that has not been optimized to the point were you can't do better.

#### Code Review

You are calling std::end() every iteration of the loop. Its not a very ineffecient call. But its still doing work they you probably don't need to in most containers.

```
    while (it != std::end(c))
```

The standard erase-remove idiom does not need to do this because it works out what it needs to remove first. Thus saving this cost (even if it is very small).

This does not work on all container types (in pre C++11):

```
             it = c.erase(it);
```

On containers like `std::vector` the erase(it) is very expensive. As you have to move all the elements down by one place each time you call erase. This is why the erase-remove idiom does it the other way. It moves elements down as many places as they need to go in a single shot without having to do multiple copies (one move per element).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have tested c.erase(it++), it seems, it doesn't work with string and vector

Comment: You are correct. SO in C++03 you need a generic way of moving the pointer or not depending on container type that does not rely on erase() returning the next iterator value (this was fixed in C++11).

Answer (score 3):

You could apply the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) using `std::remove()` from `<algorithm>`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = " Text with some spaces ";
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '),
              str.end());
    std::cout << str ;
}
```

Comment: yes. you are right. actually i looked at std::remove(). it invokes unnecessary algorithm like std::move() and std::find_if() which is a bit expensive

Comment: @MORTAL: std::move is a no-op as all it does is change the type. Also when appropriate this type change will result in faster code as objects will be moved rather than copied (so actually a good thing to have). And why is std::find_if() expensive? Its purpose is exactly what you are doing, The only difference is that it has already been tested and code reviewed a billion times to make sure it is actually very efficient.

Comment: @LokiAstari: thanks for clarifying std::move() i thought it was some sort of casting. and for std::remove() actually it  loops the container twice thats the reason it expensive

Comment: @MORTAL: No it does not. You understanding of what is happening is flawed. If finds the first occurrence of what needs to be removed. Then iterates over the remaining part of the container moving elements down the required number of slots (as more removed stuff is found the larger the move distance but it only requires one traversal of the container. The erase simply resets the end to the new end and calls all the destructors of deleted items.